# Mirror SAP internal data to an external system

Tags: postgresql, sap, slt

We would like to mirror data which is inside SAP to an external database.

Up to now there is a script which exports the data every night.

The customer wants this to happen more often. It should happen every hour.

The export is quite big, and we search for a better way to mirror data which is inside SAP to an external database.

Comment: Better ask [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) about data replication. SAP data is stored in usual realtional DB.

Comment: @Suncatcher yes, SAP does use a relational database. But in my case I would like to work with SAP technology, not with the tools of the underlying database system. I don't know if the underlying db is oracle, sql server or hana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the tag, I assume that your external database is a PostgreSQL database. In this case, I don't think you will really find a pure SAP, database independent solution.

The standard solution for this sort of replication is the [SAP SLT Server](https://help.sap.com/viewer/969cf5258b964a5ba56380da648ac84e/2.0.14/en-US/402d5f564ca7c54de10000000a441470.html). It supports taking data out of your SAP system to either a SAP target or a non-SAP target. [Currently it supports the following non-SAP targets](https://help.sap.com/viewer/969cf5258b964a5ba56380da648ac84e/2.0.14/en-US/c6ef65564ff6ce54e10000000a441470.html?q=database):

> - DB2
> - SAP MaxDB
> - Microsoft SQL Server
> - Oracle
> - Sybase ASE

As you can see, PostgreSQL is not included in there (yet). In conclusion, I see the following possibilities:

- Use SLT in combination with some other external DB that is supported.
- Use a third party replication tool like for example [SymmetricDS](https://www.symmetricds.org/).
- Depending on your source database, you might be able to use some database specific tools (e.g. SAP HANA Smart Data Integration).
- Write some custom code for doing it. In my opinion, you should try to build a sort of log table in this case, to record (using maybe triggers) which rows were inserted / updated / deleted since the last replication. IMO, this should be really a last resort, as database replication is a fairly common topic and you should not reinvent the wheel.